# 500 (Internal Server Error) when add cart

Tags: magento2

i try to add product to cart but it's refresh to same page and show this error
how to fix it.
thank you.
[image]

Comment: Are you using PWA?

Answer (score 0):

- Check the network tab in your browser's developers tools. The response of add to cart request should have some clue.
- Check **Magento logs** first. There should be some clue.
- If not, try to check the **server logs**, i.e. apache or nginx server's error logs for your host
- If you find some error, fix it.
- Else check for folder permissions in your project.

Comment: these are not errors and not causing 500 internal server error. You can check the level of message which is main.INFO.

Comment: Please check server's error log.

Comment: i check in my apache2 error.log file and i found this.
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of JsonSerializable: Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Return type of GeoIp2\\Model\\AbstractModel::jsonSerialize() should either be compatible with JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize(): mixed, or the #[\\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Ecomteck/OneStepCheckoutLib/Lib/geoip2/geoip2/src/Model/AbstractModel.php on line 63 in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:62\nStack t....

Comment: Please up-vote this answer if it helped and post this error as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run magento command one time and give permission

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento clear:flush
sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ pub/ var/
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Comment: it;s not working ToT